# sox error on white macbook 1.1 no default audio device

Tags: macos, audio, macbook, audio-recording, sox

I want to use a white macbook which purpose is recording sound with sox. I installed sox and lame via brew but when I want to record something in terminal

sox -d ada.mp3

I got the following error message:

sox FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured

I tried to reinstall lame and sox but that didn't work. Can you suggest some advice, how can I fix the problem. I've tried to google it but I not found useful informations.

Thanks for your suggestions.

I am using os 10.6.8, I want this macbook just for recording function with sox. I've tested the microphone and it is working.

Comment: Please show the debugging output with `-V5`, as in `sox -V5 -d ada.mp3`. (NB: Capital `V`.)

Comment: Thanks @chirlu for the comment. I got the same error message when I had used the "sox -V5 -d ada.mp3" command: "sox FAIL sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured". The are nothing under the AUDIO DEVICE DRIVERS: section if I type just "sox" in the command line, however on my macbook pro I see this "AUDIO DEVICE DRIVERS: coreaudio". I assume that I have no audio device driver, but how I can install coreaudio to this mac?

Comment: Well, that would be the problem, yes. I don’t know much about OS X or Homebrew, but perhaps a header file required for coreaudio support wasn’t found. Could you try `brew install sox --with-coreaudio` and post the complete output somewhere (e.g. on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/))?

Comment: I got the same result and the same output when I tried recording, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: Did you try `brew install sox --with-coreaudio`? The interesting part is not that it doesn’t word, but the output of the configuration script.

Comment: `brew install sox --with-coreaudio` did not work for me.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I also get: `play sox: Sorry, there is no default audio device configured`

Comment: Unfortunately @iago I had to make a clean install.